# Invalid input pseudo-class. It triggers invalidation CSS even if the input is empty

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Invalid input property isn't working properly. It triggers invalidation even if the input is empty. I want input to be goldenrod when it's empty. And when inserted, invalid turn to red based on pattern. And green when it's meets pattern requirement. Valid is working fine, it's turning green, but invalid no.

html:

```
<input
        className="text-field__input"
        id={id}
        name={name}
        type={type}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        required={required}
        minLength={minlength}
        title={title}
        pattern={pattern}
      />
      <label className="text-field__label" htmlFor={id}>
        {label}
</label>

<TextField
          id="username"
          label="Username"
          name="username"
          type="text"
          placeholder="user123"
          pattern="[A-Za-z\d\.]{4,12}"
          title="Username must be between 4 and 12 characters in length and contain only letters, numbers and periods"
          required
        />
```

CSS(scss):

```
.text-field__input {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4.8rem;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0 1.6rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid goldenrod;

  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
  &:valid {
    border: 3px solid green;
  }
  &:invalid {
    border: 3px solid red ;
  }
  &::placeholder {
    color: rgba($hextechgold2, 0.5);
    font-size: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  &:focus::placeholder {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your inputs are required, so can't be empty

Comment: @Konrad I see. Is there any solution without removing required?

Comment: Seems like your validation is triggered immediately instead of after pressing anything

Comment: @Konrad Yep. True

Comment: @Konrad Do you know what it may cause that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is a couple of months old wanted to help in case someone else sees this.

#### Root of the issue

Main issue here seems to be that since fields are 'required' they are being validated as invalid as they are empty as the page loads.

#### How to fix?

You can change it so that the required property is applied using Javascript, either on input (normally on 'blur' so it does not instantly change as soon as they write one character) and/or when trying to submit the form before its resolved